# Spectrum of Finite Ascent operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, operator-algebras

Im reading through the proof of the following theorem and I'm stuck on a single step.

Let $u$ be a compact operator on a Banach space $X$.  Then $\sigma(u)$ is countable, and each nonzero point of $\sigma(u)$ is an eigenvalue of $u$ and an isolated point of $\sigma(u)$.

Proof:  If $\lambda \in \sigma(u) \setminus \{0\}$, then by the Fredholm alternative, $u-\lambda I$ is not injective, so $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $u$. The operator $u-\lambda I$ has finite ascent $p$, so one can write: $$X = Y \bigoplus Z$$ where $Y = \text{ker}(u-\lambda I)^p$ and $Z = (u-\lambda I)^p(X)$.

The spaces $Y,Z$ are closed and $u$-invariant.  Hence $u-\lambda I = (u_{|Y}-\lambda I_{|Y}) \bigoplus (u_{|Z}-\lambda I_{|Z})$.  Since $(u-\lambda I)^p=0$, it follows that $\sigma(u_{|Y}) = \{\lambda\}$.

Why does $(u_{|Y}-\lambda I_{|Y})^p=0$ imply the spectrum is a singleton set $\{\lambda\}$?  I get that $\lambda \in \sigma(u_{|Y})$, but why is it the only point in the spectrum?

Any insight would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Assuming $\mu \in \sigma(u|_Y)$ means, that $u|_Y - \mu I_Y$ is not invertible. Assume $\mu \neq \lambda$. You can write $u|_Y - \mu I_Y = (\lambda-\mu)I_Y + (u|_Y - \lambda I_Y)$. The first term is invertible and the second is nilpotent by assumtion. Now the Neumann series shows, that $u|_Y - \mu I_Y$ is invertible. So indeed every element of the spectrum must be $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Could you explain what term you are applying the Von Neumann series to?  I think I understand however, since the spectral radius of $u|_{Y}-\lambda I|_{Y}$ is given by $\lim_{n} ||(u|_{Y}-\lambda I_{Y})||^{1/n} = 0$, so $0 = \sigma(u|_{Y}-\lambda I|_{Y})$, which implies that $\{\lambda\} = \sigma(u|_{Y})$

Comment: You can pull out $(\lambda - \mu)$ and look at $I_Y - (\lambda - \mu)^{-1}(\lambda I_Y - u|_Y)$. The inverse is then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} [(\lambda - \mu)^{-1}(\lambda I_Y - u|_Y)]^k$, which is a finite sum, since $\lambda I_Y - u|_Y$ is nilpotent.